# Bootstrap glyphicon after position

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, glyphicons

## The problem

I want to display a glyphicon icon after a text. In the documentation, there are only before examples as you can see here: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#glyphicons-examples

```
<div class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right">Next</div>
```

## My solutions

#### Solution 1

```
<div>Next<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></div>
```

#### Solution 2

```
#next.custom-chevron-right:after {
    font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
    content: "\e080";
}
```

```
<div id="next" class="glyphicon custom-chevron-right">Next</div>
```

Source example: [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/aleixfabra/wCre9tx5p5)

## My question

Is there a better way to do it just with bootstrap classes?

Answer (score 29):

There are 2 ways to typically add glyphicons (or any other icon font being used). The first way it to add them via html.

```
<div>Next <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></div>
// Be sure to add a space in between your text and the icon
```

The second way it to do it using CSS. At a minimum, you **must include** the *font-family* and *character code*.

```
<div><span>Next</span></div>

span::after {
    font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
    content: "\e080";
}
```

Obviously, using the CSS method you can then add additional styling but this example shows you the minimum needed to get thte icon to appear in the relative correct place.

Answer (score 2):

Your first solution is the best solution. There's not really any point in doing it another way as that's how you put glyphicons onto your website with Bootstrap anyway

Comment: Actually, I use CSS to add icons (and other things) fairly frequently. A good example is when I want to add an icon to a menu item in WordPress. Using the CSS is the quickest/easiest way...